# How configure Lapis for external IP address?

Tags: nginx, openresty

I have installed Lapis with OpenResty. By default it works on localhost address.
How to configure Lapis for exert IP? So I need that it works from my dedicated IP address

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to edit nginx configuration file.
Take a look at http://nginx.org/en/docs/beginners_guide.html

Look for `server_name`directive
http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html

Comment: I have default setting:` location / {} and lister 8080`

Comment: Show your whole nginx config. Are you sure it is not firewall issue?